WIFI drops out when running anything intensive
Running windows 11. I have a fairly new pc <1 year old and for the last few months I've had this issue where the moment I start running anything computationally intensive, whether it's installing a new program, running a video game or anything, my WIFI speed will just plummet, and if my computer remains running that high eventually I'll just get no internet signal. It's definitely not my wifi. I've never had this issue on my old wifi connected on these bandwidths and my wifi is still working perfectly fine on my phone or any other device.
This is particularly an issue when I'm connected to the 5Ghz bandwidth of my WIFI. When I'm connected to it on the normal bandwidth (I think 2.4ghz) the issue is much less prevalent (but I believe it is still there).
This is my PC build: https://au.pcpartpicker.com/list/MBLZJy
I've yet to see another instance of this occurring to anyone that I can find online.

Hello, Wi-Fi issue is tricky here a few suggestion. Update your wi-fi driver to the lastest version, unistall and reinstall from device manager your wi-fi driver, try to forget the SSID and reconnect yourself, restart your internet modem. is your computer placement far away from your modem ? or are you in a room with metal ?
